# Where saves files after php upload?

Tags: php, file-upload

I know, how to use upload. Is I think right, that files is in temporary folder in HTTP server after upload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']`contains the path to the temporary file that resides on the server. The file should exist on the server in a temporary directory with a temporary name.

`uploadedfile` is the reference we assigned in our HTML form. This identifies which uploaded file we are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed, files go to the temp folder of you sever host OS. If you have Windows, for instance, it would go into C:\Windows\temp

Hope it helps!!

When I say:

> If you have Windows

I mean if you have Windows in your local host server for testing, so you may get the idea

Answer (score 1):

Yes it resides on the server in a temporary directory with a temporary name.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.